# Navigator.pop(context) Not returning to the Previous Screen Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, post, flutter-navigation, scaffold

I have a Contacts Page with List of contacts and a `FloatingActionButton` which goes to `Add_Contact()` page.
There is a `form` and a `FlatButton` SAVE on the `AppBar` which when clicked posts the form data and should return back to the previous list of contacts page.

But whenever I click on the save button it just stays on that page doesn't return back to the previous page. I had also tried adding a `SnackBar` and then a `FlushBar` to show that the contact is saved but even that doesn't show up on the screen.

**contacts_page.dart:**

```
 //Rest of the code above
 floatingActionButton: _bottomButtons(context),
        ));
  }

  Widget _bottomButtons(BuildContext context) {
    return _tabController.index == 0
        ? FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return AddContacts();
              }));
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.person_add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ))
        : FloatingActionButton(
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                return AddCompany();
              }));
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          );
  }
```

**add_contacts.dart:**

```
 Future saveContact() async {
    final String firstName = _firstName.text;
    final String lastName = _lastName.text;
    final String email = _email.text;

    final AddContactModel contact =
        await API_Manager().addContact(firstName, lastName, email);
    Navigator.pop(context); //Not working
    setState(() {
      _contact = contact;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Add Contact'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    await saveContact();
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'SAVE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                shape:
                    CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _ipCountryCode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'IP Country Code',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Time First Seen',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              timeFirstSeen = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ), 
                  //Rest of the Code Below
```

**Here are the screenshots for the two screens:**

[First Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92spX.png)

[Second Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8X7q0.png)

*Also offtopic, is there a better way to post form data having huge amount of fields? Currently I'm using HttpClient and I'm only able to post 3 field values firstname, lastname and email. I tried adding other fields which are present in the form into the request's body and parameters but it just wouldnt post them.I also tried giving the entire JSON model to the request's body and function's parameter but i didnt know how to actually call the request function and assign the TextFormField controllers to its values to post the data. If you can help me out with this as well it would be great.*

**EDIT:**

**API_Manager():**

```
 Future<AddContactModel> addContact(
      String firstName, String lastName, String email) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    String addContactUrl =
        "https://example.com/ma/api/contacts/new";
    String basicAuth = 'Basic examplebasicauthkey';
    var response = await client.post(addContactUrl, headers: <String, String>{
      'authorization': basicAuth,
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }, body: {
      "firstname": firstName,
      "lastname": lastName,
      "email": email,
    });
    // print(response.statusCode);
    //developer.log(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final String responseString = response.body;
      return addContactModelFromJson(responseString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `_formKey.currentState.validate()` is true?

Comment: I don't see any validator function assign in your form field. I wrote a test app, and the `_formKey.currentState.validate()` will return true if there are no validator. Probably  an error in your `API_Manager()`

Comment: @LuisA.Chaglla Yes it is true because the data is being posted to the server.

Comment: @AlexanderDischberg should I attach my `addContact()`  function from `API_Manager()` ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? if not, maybe the call to `API_Manager().addContact` never resolves

Comment: @LuisA.Chaglla No errors but when I try to add more parameters to the request's function and body, they don't get posted to the server. I've been having several problems with the POST function lately and also it's my first time working with API's. I'll edit the question and attach the function. It probably might have some problems. Please have a look, Thank you.

Comment: Comment the line `API_Manager().addContact` of `saveContact` and see if it works.
I don't see any reson for `Navigator.pop(context)` to not work

Comment: @LuisA.Chaglla Yess, it worked! But how do i make it work with `API_Manager().addContact`?

Comment: I just added 'Navigator.pop(context) before this `API_Manager().addContact` line and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well it "works".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232012/discussion-between-luis-a-chaglla-and-shreyas-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 0):

Push

```
Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ProductDetailView(),
            ));
```

Pop

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Can you check if this works?

Comment: Nope, Still not working. Does it have something to do with `RefreshIndicator`. Cause i saw another post where `Navigator.pop` didn't work when he used a `RefreshIndicator`.